# Using Placeholders in a URL string

Tags: objective-c, asp.net-web-api

I have a url that retrieves data from a Web API which looks like this with the entry of "Pizza Hut":

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/Pizza  Hut?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY";
```

This URL will return all the menu items of Pizza Hut.

Now I want to take a step beyond hard coding values, and so I created a text box where users can enter their own restaurant, and the web api should return data.

Here is an example of that:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", searchText.text];
```

All I did here was change the "Pizza Hut" to "%@".

However, I get a warning from the compiler saying:

"More '%' conversions than data arguments. As you would expect, the API returns no data, for this code doesn't seem to be working.

How would I re-write this string so that I could put the placeholder in there?

Answer (score 1):

You have other percent symbols that need to be escaped properly. You want:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=0%%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%%2Cbrand_name%%2Citem_id%%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", searchText.text];
```

Basically, add a 2nd `%` symbol before all of the `%` symbols that you actually want to appear in the string.

BTW - make sure you properly escape the search text so special characters (such as spaces) are properly encoded.

Comment: +1 for basically saying that you need to use ```stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding``` This is an important step which many forget